# Watir-webdriver: Safari

Tags: ruby, safari, watir, watir-webdriver

I've recently started using watir-webdriver and so far am a big fan. However I need to be able to test Safari too, and I don't have access to a mac to be able to use Safari-Watir.

Does anyone know a good alternative to use for testing Safari on a windows machine? (In Ruby of course)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(important, see UPDATE below)
the Selenium Webdriver folks are apparently waiting for something from Apple in order to support safari.  I would not hold your breath.

Apple does have a version of Safari for the PC, I'm not sure how good the current version is, the initial releases were.. um, well, lets just say they had issues (*lots* of issues)

Personally (mostly for security reasons) I would not run it nor recommend anyone use it for any purpose other than downloading Chrome or Firefox.  But unfortunately a lot of apple users use it because it's what came with their systems, which means to the extent apple users are part of your target market, you have to test on it.

For the moment that means you'll need to use Safariwatir, which has not as far as I can tell had an update for a year or more.

the current state of support on both the Selenium/Webdriver side and the Safariwatir side was discussed recently in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/watir-general/browse_thread/thread/cd7d0b093da020d0) in the watir general group on google

**UPDATE**
  Webdriver now has Safari support, which makes direct support of safari (I think on a mac only at this point) possible.   See http://watirmelon.com/2012/04/17/using-watir-webdriver-with-safari-at-last/ for more info.. still a bit DYI but I'm sure it will get more accessable soon.

Comment: Well I guess that about sums it up. Thanks!

Comment: New updates,  added update to my answer, or see Dave's newly added answer also

Answer (score 2):

Mike, seems this is available now. Alister Scott wrote up some instructions on his blog [Using Watir-Webdriver with Safari At Last](http://watirmelon.com/2012/04/17/using-watir-webdriver-with-safari-at-last/#comment-3876)

Unfortunately this still a bit DYI because you have to build your own safari extension, which requires getting certificates and such from apple, and I'm not sure if you can create the right environment to build that stuff on anything other than a mac.